# Как спроектировать таблицы для хранения значений для М:М и как потом описать мапинг для hibernate?

Tags: java, postgresql, hibernate

Есть таблицы `thing` и `property` (М:М), а также таблица для хранения их связей `thing2property`.

У меня мапятся эти таблицы следующими классами

```
@Entity
@Table
public class Thing implements Serializable {

   @Id
   @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
   @Column
   private Integer id;

   @Column
   private String name;

   @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
   @JoinTable(name = "thing2property", 
     joinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "thing_id") }, 
     inverseJoinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "property_id") })
   private List<ThingProperty> thingProperties = new ArrayList<ThingProperty>();
}

@Entity
@Table
public class ThingProperty implements Serializable {

   @Id
   @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
   @Column
   private Integer id;

   @Column
   private String name;

   @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
   @JoinTable(name = "thing2property", 
     joinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "property_id") }, 
     inverseJoinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "thing_id") })
   private List<Thing> things = new ArrayList<Thing>();
}
```

Я обрезал классы для удобства, допускаю что мог вырезать что-то важное и что в таком виде они не будут работать, но полные версии этих классов у меня мапят данные исправно, поэтому надеюсь от точного синтаксиса можно абстрагироваться.

Для примера пусть в этих таблицах будет следующее содержимое

`property`

```
id | name
---+-------
 1 | color
---+-------
 2 | width
---+-------
 3 | weight
```

`thing`

```
id | name
---+-----
 1 | pen
---+-----
 2 | ball
---+-----
 3 | cap
```

`thing2property`

```
thing_id | property_id
---------+-------------
    1    |      1
---------+-------------
    1    |      3
---------+-------------
    2    |      3
---------+-------------
    3    |      3
```

Но для каждой пары предмет-свойство предусмотрен ввод произвольного строкового значения, которое нужно сохранить в базе. Например цвет ручки - синий, вес ручки - 50гр, вес мяча - 500гр

Первая мысль у меня была добавить третье поле в таблицу `thing2property.value`. Но как тогда это значение вынимать автоматическим мапингом? Попробовал нагуглить, может запросы ввожу кривые, но что-то все не то, может тут к решению задачи заходить нужно с другой стороны?

Подумывал еще в виде json хранить в одном из столбцов значения для связанных записей, но как потом criteria генерить для поиска по значениям, не понятно.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Попробовал нагуглить

Видимо не удачно ключевые слова подбирали, лично мне Google сразу предложил правильно дополнить и в первой же строчке выдачи представил [ссылку на вариант решения](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5127262/1341148).

Суть предлагаемого решения заключается в том, что следует заменить одно соотношение `Many To Many` на каскадные соотношения `One To Many` и `Many To One`. Для этого `thing2property` следует выделить в самостоятельную сущность, добавив в таблицу свойство `value` (как Вы и предлагали). Маппинги получатся примерно такие:

```
@Entity
@Table
public class Thing implements Serializable {
@OneToMany(mappedBy = "thing")
private Set<Thing2Property> props;



@Entity
@Table
public class Thing2Property implements Serializable {

@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "thing_id")
private Thing thing;

@Column
private String value;

@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "property_id")
private ThingProperty property;
```